# Is there a weapon that has the heavy property and the finesse property (or could this be obtained)?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I was looking at a character I was finishing, and I realized there are no weapons that seem to have the Finesse property and Heavy property at the same time. I got thinking, **Could a weapon have the Finesse property** ***and*** **the Heavy property?**

(I think not, but there might be a way to achieve this with magic. **Is there a way to achieve this at all???**)

Can this be **OBTAINED VIA MAGIC**?

Comment: It might be a better approach to instead tell us what you’re trying to do: is there some build or combo you’re trying to put together that would have good use for a weapon with both properties?

Comment: Not in particular. Just want an example of a weapon that could possibly have the Finesse and Heavy property at the same time. I allow any such weapon to be used.

Comment: Weapons like metal guitars?

Comment: Yes......... But... this would be a modern world...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### No such weapons exist.

There is no weapon in official material with both the heavy and finesse properties. This should not be surprising: the point of the finesse property is that the weapon is light and your ability with it is determined by your dexterity, not your strength. Additionally, there are no official rules for creating or crafting weapons that would allow for a weapon with both properties.

Answer (score 10):

### There is no such weapon

First, there is no weapon that has both the **heavy** and the **finesse** property in the rules. Secondly, there are no explicit rules to create new weapons; in fact, the game recommends that for weapons not in the current weapon lists, you re-skin existing ones (*DMG*, p. 41 for Wuxia weapons), which means you probably should be careful to not create something unbalanced by introducing new weapons.

As you are looking for a character you are creating, there also is no need for such a combo. If your character is small, heavy only would stop you from using the weapon. If you are medium sized, heavy has no effect for you.<sup>1</sup>

That is because the **heavy** property is misleadingly named. It reads (p. 147, *PHB*):

> **Heavy**. Small creatures have disadvantage on attack rolls with heavy weapons. *A heavy weapon’s size and bulk make it too large for a Small creature* to use effectively.

So it has nothing to do with weight, it is about unwieldiness and size and only serves to stop small characters from using a weapon. For example, the longbow, weighing only 2 pounds is a heavy weapon, while a greatclub, at 10 pounds among heaviest weapons in the list, is not.

---

<sup>1</sup> One exception would be if you also have other features like Great Weapon Master, which would allow you to combine using Dexterity as the ability modifier with adding -5 to your attack for +10 to damage. Your DM would need to decide if they feel this kind of cheese is something they want in their game.

Comment: There is at least one case where Heavy is a desirable property - the Great Weapon Master feat allows +10 dmg for a -5 to hit for heavy weapons.

Comment: @Jon, Good point-out, I added it to the answer. I should have thought of it myself, one player in our group sweet talked out DM to be allowed a one handed "heavy" mace for exactly that exploit (while also getting the benefit of a shield). Now they are complaining that the DM prefers to attack other players, and not them with their 27 AC with *shield* and a shield.

Comment: Just one question(unrelated to the question, but a question regarding the answer you provided).  What if you CAN'T reskin custom weapons(I specifically want to add boomerangs, heavy boomerangs, and brass knuckles to the weapons table.) What do you do then?

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 What do you mean by "can't reskin'" As in, your DM won't let you refluff an existing item? If that's the case, there's a bigger issue than the item :)

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 If your DM does  not even let you reskin an existing weapon, there *still* is no such weapon, and your chances likely are slim to get one